# Comparing the content of multiple XML Files and Match them

Tags: c#, xml

I got two folders, and each folder contains a certain amount of .xml files named differently. Each XML file contains one particular line which looks like this:

```
<general name = "something" ....... version = "something" .... >
```

Each folder has one .xml file that share the same `name`, which has the value `"something"` in the above example. However, their file name is different.
My goal is, for every file in each folder, to match them by their name in the .xml file and compare their version number.

Comment: Read the files, parse the XML, compare the attributes. Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: Well, for a vast amount of files I would always compare 1 attribute against every file's attribute of the other folder until I find the correct one, which seemed a little bit ineffective.

Comment: You did not write how big that "certain amount" is. So you have a solution, but it is too slow?

Comment: No, I was just brainstorming before trying to code the solution and would prefer an optimized solution.

Comment: You might first read all the (filename, name, version) tuples from one folder into memory, and then process the other folder until there is a match. This would be O(N) instead of O(N^2) with your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] FOLDERS = {@"c:\temp\folder1\", @"c:\temp\folder2"};

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<General> generals0 = new List<General>();
            List<General> generals1 = new List<General>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
            {
                string folder = FOLDERS[i];
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.Xml"))
                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
                    XElement xGeneral = doc.Descendants("general").FirstOrDefault();
                    if (xGeneral != null)
                    {
                        string name = (string)xGeneral.Attribute("name");
                        string version = (string)xGeneral.Attribute("version");
                        if (name != null)
                        {
                            General general = new General();
                            switch(i)
                            {
                                case 0 :
                                    generals0.Add(general);
                                    break;
                                case 1 :
                                    generals1.Add(general);
                                    break;
                            }

                            general.filename = file;
                            general.name = name;
                            general.version = version; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //join to lists
            var results = (from g0 in generals0
                           join g1 in generals1 on g0.name equals g1.name
                           select new { g0 = g0, g1 = g1 }
                           ).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class General
    {
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a very beginner to C#, could you please explain to me why we need the `break` here?

Comment: The break exits the loop so you stop looking at the files in the folder after you find the first file with the tag general.

Comment: I see. However, I need to check every file and find their "counterpart" in the other folder. So I guess in that case the break will not be needed?

Comment: You said you needed to find one file in each folder. Later you may need to look at rest of the files.

Comment: yeah, that was poorly explained by me. It is the two matching files for every file in each folder.

Comment: I updated code to join the results from both folders.

Comment: I updated code to add version to the results.

Comment: That is actually very cool, ty! Could the same result be achieved with using Linq for adding the General Objects to the List?

Comment: You cannot Add to existing list with Linq.  The linq would be more complicated than the code posted.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0, do

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:variable name="one" 
                select="map:merge(collection('folder1?select=*.xml') 
                    //general ! map{@name : string(@version)})"/>
  <xsl:variable name="two" 
                select="map:merge(collection('folder2?select=*.xml') 
                    //general ! map{@name : string(@version)})"/>
  <xsl:variable name="combined" 
                select="map:merge(($one, $two), 
                                  map{'duplicates': 'combine'})"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="map:keys($combined)">
                name={.} : versions={$combined?.}
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```